# Weird hover effect

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show the caption on my products when you hover. I manage to get it, but the black won't show black, like I have some kind of white background on top of my effect. You can see it [there](http://www.terranewyork.com/collections/view-all)

Here's the CSS I added

.product:hover .reveal img {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 1;
    }

```
.reveal .hidden {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.reveal:hover .hidden {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}

.reveal .caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) !important;
    font: 12px/1.4em sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    text-align: center;
}

.reveal .hidden .caption .centered {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Do you think it is as basic as a z-index problem, or is it more in the way I constructed it ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Your `.caption` has a solid background and covers the entire image's size. Make the background semi-transparent.

Comment: Also: if you're abs-posing something you *probably* shouldn't use margins on it unless you have good reason; `top:-20px;` will have the same effect in your context as `top:0; margin-top:-20px;`. It's only if something is going to use `:auto` as a value while abs-pos'd (or if it makes animation cleaner) that you should use margins on abs-pos'd elements. Oh and:  ***`!important` HISS!!***

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have an `hover` effect the animate the `.image-wrapper` to `opacity:0.5`. If you set `.product-grid .image-wrapper {opacity:1 !important)` (just for the test you can see that the black is black.

So what can you do?

Do the fadeOut effect on the `.reveal > img`. In this way the `.product-grid .image-wrapper` will stay `opacity:1`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.reveal:hover .hidden { 
      z-index: 0;
      opacity: 0.8;    

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems was the `.caption` was the same size as the image it was positioned over, and had a `1.0 alpha` background- meaning the caption box covered the image entirely once the z-index let it pop in front.

The other problem is the js/jQ doing an animation on rollover. Just nix the code adding the hover handler to it. If you want a fade-in/out still, put the base `z-index` on your caption to make it naturally be in front, and animate its `opacity` up to 100% on `:hover`. This is opposed to animating the opacity of the whole tile from 100% to 50% and switching the stacking order.

Answer (score -1):

```
.image-wrapper:hover {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

that will fix it. When you hover it goes to 0.5, this will stop it.

Comment: Obligatory ***`!important` HISS!!***. If your fix relies on using `!important`, 99% chance it's a hack that could've been fixed in a better way. In this case, turning off the js-driven `opacity` animation.

Comment: that's true, it's a quick fix.

Comment: Thank you Draity, it work very well for the purpose.